# jenkins job for protractor cucumber

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, protractor

I have a protractor cucumber intellij project. I want to create a jenkins job that can run my tests. I have no idea how to do it. I could not find any tutorials that explain where to start from.

Answer (score 1):

Well , in case you are running Jenkins instance in your local machine , its pretty straightforward.

> In build step , add the command you want to run . I suppose if you are
>   using Protractor , it will most probably look like this :

```
protractor conf.js
```

Just make sure you are putting appropriate path for conf.js. Think of it this way , what command you will type in command prompt to run your script .

> Rest of the configuration , you can learn from
>   :[http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/][1]
>
> [1]: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Grunt` and run your protractor as a grunt task. Please refer to this link for the configuration - you can refer section to the which talks about running protractor as a Grunt task.

Link -> [Running Protractor in Jenkins](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automating-angular-apps-using-protractor-integrating-continuous)